# addEventListener stops after the first execution

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm running into an issue with my current JS project. It's a simple library where the user inputs the info and spits it out onto the page. I have a delete button that I add to each new div, which I've added event listeners to the buttons. When I click delete, it will delete the first one - but that's it. It stops working if i want to delete more than one book.

I think my problem is how I'm targeting the data-set/index values that i assign each div, but I'm not sure. I've tried for loops, for each, etc and can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
const book1 = new Book('inserttitlehere', 'His name?', 63, false)
const book2 = new Book('kill bill', 'author2', 653, false)
const book3 = new Book('oh yeah baby', 'author3', 323, false)
const book4 = new Book('kill me now', 'author4', 132, true)
library.push(book1, book2, book3, book4)

// Book constructor
function Book(title, author, pages, completed) {
  this.title = title
  this.author = author
  this.pages = pages
  this.completed = completed
}

const main = document.querySelector('main');
const form = document.querySelector('.form');


//Function to add books to the DOM 
function displayBooks() {
  let dataIndex = 0;
  main.innerHTML = '';
  library.forEach(book => {
    const bookElement = document.createElement('div')
    bookElement.classList.add('book');
    bookElement.setAttribute('data-index', dataIndex);

    bookElement.innerHTML = `
    <h3> ${book.title} </h3>
    <p> Author: ${book.author}</p>
    <p> Pages: ${book.pages}</p>
    Completed: <input type="checkbox"> ${book.completed} <br>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    `
    main.appendChild(bookElement);
    dataIndex++;
  })
}
displayBooks();

//Add new book to library
function addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages, completed) {
  const newBook = new Book(title, author, pages, completed)
  library.push(newBook);
}

//Deleting a book from the array
let deleteBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.book .delete');

deleteBtns.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const index = button.parentNode.dataset['data-index'];
    deleteBook(index);
  })
});

function deleteBook(index) {
  library.splice(index, 1);
  displayBooks();
}


form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const title = document.querySelector('#title').value;
  const author = document.querySelector('#author').value;
  const pages = document.querySelector('#pages').value;
  addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages, false);
  document.forms[0].reset();
})

console.log(library);
console.log(deleteBtns);
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Library</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <h1>Library</h1>
    <button class="add-book-btn">NEW BOOK</button>
  </nav>
  <main></main>

  <div class="modal">
    <form class="form">
      <p class="close"></p>
      <h2>Add Book</h2>
      <div class="user-input">
        <label for="">Title</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="title" required>
      </div>
      <div class="user-input">
        <label for="">Author</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="author" required>
      </div>
      <div class="user-input">
        <label for="">Pages</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="pages" required>
      </div>
      <div class="user-input">
        <label for="">Read?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="read">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A javascript framework like react, vue or svelte would be a great use case for something like this

Comment: @moritzsalla I thought the same thing

Comment: Your basic problem is when you replace innerHTML you lose event listeners that were attached to any of those elements. Even though the new html is basically identical, it creates new dom element objects. You are replacing all book elements just to remove one. Look into how to remove the parent element of the button instead and leave the other book elements alone

Comment: @Unwell4 Perhaps reconsider your choice for Best Answer after a careful review of Charlietfl's submission. Good question - nicely composed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are building an app like this it's often best to remove the parts that aren't relevant such as the form and all it;s associated functions in order to work on specific parts of it like these user interactions.

Here's a scaled down version with a completely different approach that adds event listeners to the book elements individually as you create them.

Then instead of worrying about indexing, use array methods to find the book object in the library. So rather than rebuild all the elements when you  remove one you simply remove both the element and the object in the array.

It's broken down into smaller functions like `addBookEvents()` then within each different event handler uses either `Array.prototype.find()` or `Array.prototype.findIndex()` to modify library.

Your approach of rebuilding all the elements just to change the indexing is not very scalable or efficient. In order to create the library array used here I just used your `library.push(book1,book2...)` and then ran `console.log(JSON.stringify(library))` and pasted it into this code to keep it lean for this stage.

Note that I changed `data-index` to `data-title` on the elements with assumption that titles will be unique in the array. That then allows searching array to find the specific book object. Using a unique book `id` is more reliable in case of title duplications

```js
const main = document.getElementById('books-list')

library.forEach(createBookElement)

function handleDeleteClick(event) {
  const bookElem = event.target.closest('.book');
  const title = bookElem.dataset.title;
  bookElem.remove();
  removeFromLibrary(title)
  console.log(title)
}

function handleCompleteChange(event){
    const bookElem = event.target.closest('.book');
    const title = bookElem.dataset.title;
    const checked = event.target.checked;
    toggleLibraryComplete(title, checked)

}

function removeFromLibrary(title) {
  const idx = library.findIndex(book => book.title === title);
  if (idx > -1) {
    library.splice(idx, 1);
    console.log('library length =', library.length)
  }
}

function toggleLibraryComplete(title, checked){
     const book = library.find(book => book.title === title);
     book.completed = checked;
     console.log(JSON.stringify(book))
}

function addBookEvents(bookElement){
   const button = bookElement.querySelector('.delete');  
   button.addEventListener('click', handleDeleteClick);
   const checkbox = bookElement.querySelector('.book-complete');
   checkbox.addEventListener('change', handleCompleteChange);
}



function createBookElement(book) {
  const bookElement = document.createElement('div')
  bookElement.classList.add('book');
  bookElement.setAttribute('data-title', book.title);

  bookElement.innerHTML = `
    <h3> ${book.title} </h3>
    <p> Author: ${book.author}</p>
    <p> Pages: ${book.pages}</p>
    Completed: <input class="book-complete" type="checkbox" ${book.completed && 'checked'}> ${book.completed} <br>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    `;
  // add the event listeners for delete and completed 
  addBookEvents(bookElement);
  main.appendChild(bookElement);

}

//console.log(JSON.stringify(library))
```

```html
<main id="books-list"></main>
<script>
const library =
[{"title":"inserttitlehere","author":"His name?","pages":63,"completed":true},{"title":"kill bill","author":"author2","pages":653,"completed":false},{"title":"oh yeah baby","author":"author3","pages":323,"completed":false},{"title":"kill me now","author":"author4","pages":132,"completed":true}];
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It definitely makes sense to test things on a smaller scale like that. This is really nice, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var library = []

const book1 = new Book('inserttitlehere', 'His name?', 63, false)
const book2 = new Book('kill bill', 'author2', 653, false)
const book3 = new Book('oh yeah baby', 'author3', 323, false)
const book4 = new Book('kill me now', 'author4', 132, true)
library.push(book1, book2, book3, book4)

// Book constructor
function Book(title, author, pages, completed) {
  this.title = title
  this.author = author
  this.pages = pages
  this.completed = completed
}

const main = document.querySelector('main');
const form = document.querySelector('.form');


//Function to add books to the DOM 
function displayBooks() {
  let dataIndex = 0;
  main.innerHTML = '';
  library.forEach(book => {
    const bookElement = document.createElement('div')
    bookElement.classList.add('book');
    bookElement.setAttribute('data-index', dataIndex);

    bookElement.innerHTML = `
    <h3> ${book.title} </h3>
    <p> Author: ${book.author}</p>
    <p> Pages: ${book.pages}</p>
    Completed: <input type="checkbox"> ${book.completed} <br>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    `
    main.appendChild(bookElement);
    dataIndex++;
  })
}
displayBooks();

//Add new book to library
function addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages, completed) {
  const newBook = new Book(title, author, pages, completed)
  library.push(newBook);
  displayBooks();
}

function addListener() {
  //Deleting a book from the array
  let deleteBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.book .delete');

  deleteBtns.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const index = button.parentNode.dataset['data-index'];
      deleteBook(index);
    })
  });
}

addListener();

function deleteBook(index) {
  library.splice(index, 1);
  displayBooks();
  addListener();
}

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const title = document.querySelector('#title').value;
  const author = document.querySelector('#author').value;
  const pages = document.querySelector('#pages').value;
  addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages, false);
  document.forms[0].reset();
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Library</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <h1>Library</h1>
    <button class="add-book-btn">NEW BOOK</button>
  </nav>
  <main></main>

  <div class="modal">
    <form class="form">
      <p class="close"></p>
      <h2>Add Book</h2>
      <div class="user-input">
        <label for="">Title</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="title" required>
      </div>
      <div class="user-input">
        <label for="">Author</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="author" required>
      </div>
      <div class="user-input">
        <label for="">Pages</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="pages" required>
      </div>
      <div class="user-input">
        <label for="">Read?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="read">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

First off, `library` was not defined so I added an array `library` at the top. Then, I addressed the problem.

The problem was that every time you delete a book, `deleteBtn` and the button event listeners were being altered, because the buttons they reference were being deleted. So, just reinitialize them every time you delete a book. I did this by wrapping it in a function and recalling it every time it is needed.

Note that I also added an extra line of `displayBooks` under `addBookToLibrary`, to make sure that the page is "refreshed" when a book is added.

Comment: I forgot to past the very top lines where library was defined :/ This makes a ton of sense. Thank you for explaining it so well. Cheers!